# C system call handler referencing functions with different return types and number of arguments

Tags: c, callback, system-calls

My system call handler receives an index mapped to a function, and is supposed to call that function, extracting its arguments from the stack. How can I abstract the function type and number of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

For do it, you have to define a `struct` and pass `struct pointer` to your `callback function`, Then each element of your `struct` can be an argument of your `callback function`